# Python print not skipping to the end line in command prompt

Tags: python, cmd, command

I am writing a console program using python.

As you must be knowing, when a program is running and then a user scrolls up the command window, when the program prints something the window itself scrolls down to the end.

But when I do this `print("\033[A\033[A")` to remove the last printed line in the command prompt, it does not scroll down to the bottom and remove the last printed line but instead clears up the last line on the part of the screen that's visible to me.

What should I do to solve this?

Please help. Thank you!

I am on windows 10

Comment: either you can move the cursor with ansi command to the end or, if the print command moves the cursor already, you could print a random and then remove the last line `print('deleteme',end='') print("\033[A\033[A")`

Comment: Maybe print something real and then delete two lines?

Comment: Thank you! It works! But the thing that is printed isn't removed.